# php mail not sent but returning true hmailserver

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a mail using php but mail is not showing on my gmail. `$mail return true`. I am using hmailserver and WAMP. any help would be appreciated.

```
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $cc = $_POST['cc'];
    //$headers =  "From: ".$_POST['from']."\r\n"."CC: ".$_POST['cc'];

    $headers = 'From: Sigma Web Site <'.$_POST['from'].'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' .$_POST['cc']. "\r\n";

    ini_set("sendmail_from", "iit@yahoo.com");

    $mail = mail( $to, "Mail", $message, $headers);

    echo($mail);

    if($mail)
    {
        echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "Mail sending failed."; 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;).

```
    $emailFROM = $_POST['from'];
    $for = $_POST['to'];
    $sub = "Subject";
    $mes = $_POST['Message'];
    if(Mail($for, $sub, $mes, "From: " . $emailFROM))
    { 
        echo "(OK| <pre>$emailFROM<b>$for</b> - <b>$sub</b> - <b>$mes</b></pre>)";
    } else {
        echo "(Error)";
    }
```

Comment: (OK|
iit@yahoo.comimransilvake@gmail.com - Subject - messgaetxt
) i am getting this